# AIR apps and processes

Tags: air, process

AIR apps are generally very little in size (a few Mb). Why, when you launch them, the task manager shows n processes for n apps launched? And why the memory used is more than 30 Mb (for single process)? I imagine it is the runtime: but why the runtime doesn't load only once (and then is used to load n apps)? I noticed Chrome does quite the same: when you open a new tab it creates a new process. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is how the task manager displays the amount of memory being used. The "Working set" is what is displayed by default in the task man and that can include shared memory. To see memory that is allocated to that tab/air app you would probably have to make a call to their respective run-times. (or in chrome you can press shift-esc and it will tell you how the memory stats)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome uses one process per tab so if one crash the rest of the tabs and the browser itself keeps working.
About the Adobe Air RAM usage... keep in mind that it uses Flash and that is nothing lightweight.

Comment: The problem is NOT Flash: Flash takes very low memory. AIR is based on the WebKit engine (maybe this uses RAM).